# how to open fragment directly from activity without split second of activity layout appear?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

hi i wanna know is there any way to show fragment from activity when app open WITHOUT split second of activity layout appear before showing the fragment layout? if there is a way could you tell me how to do it please? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your activity onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     switchFragment(new yourFragment());
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rootLayout,fragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: may i know why not use add? why use replace?

Comment: anyway  i think it will crash the app without specify the setContent before run the switchFragment

Comment: that you have to do I just wrote the code for switching the fragment when activity starts and you can use add also I have used replace because then you can use the same method if you want to switch fragment somewhere else also in your appliaction

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragment=new MainFragment();

android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);

ft.commit();
```

Comment: thanks anyway but i know how to create a fragment..., but it always show the MainActivity for a split second before showing up the fragment layout.

Comment: does your activity has other views too that you don't want to show??